# Iterating through map using for loop not working

Tags: python

Code :

```
def find_max_score(arr):
    max_score=0
    for i in arr:
        if(max_score < i):
            max_score=i
    return max_score

def find_runner_up_score(max_score,arr):
    runner_up_score=0
    for i in arr:
        print(f"{i} < {max_score} and {i} > {runner_up_score}")
        if(i < max_score and i > runner_up_score):
            runner_up_score=i
            print(runner_up_score)
    print(f"Runner up score : {runner_up_score}")
    return runner_up_score

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = map(int, input().split())

    max_score=find_max_score(arr)
    runner_up_score=find_runner_up_score(max_score,arr)
```

Input:

```
5
2 3 6 6 5
```

Expected Output:

```
Runner up score : 5
```

Actual Output:

```
Runner up score : 0
```

The `find_max_score` finds the max score. The `find_runner_up_score` function finds the runner up (second highest) score.

The loop in `find_max_score` function works fine but the loop in `find_runner_up_score` function does not work.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: you have to convert map into list, then it will retain values.

Comment: @ForamJ Can you explain why the `find_max_score` function works but `find_runner_up_score` does not ? They are using the similar loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you are using a map object which is a stateful iterator. This means that it can only be looped over once. This is what happens when you call `find_max_score` first. Once that's done, the whole object is looped over and there's nothing left to iterate by the time `find_runner_up_score` is called.

This is why we can process the input by converting it into a list.

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Comment: Can you explain why the `find_max_score` function works but `find_runner_up_score` does not ? They are using the similar loops

Comment: Good question. Why can you loop `arr` when it is created, but not when you pass it in as a parameter?

Comment: @SiddharthManthan How is the `find_runner_up_score` not working? The max value is 6 and the next highest is 5. Is there any other issue you are facing?

Comment: @vnk Check https://www.online-python.com/3loQ1BsNtR. The function returns 0 and the statment `print(f"{i} < {max_score} and {i} > {runner_up_score}")` under the for loop block does not get executed.

Comment: @SiddharthManthan You haven't modified `arr = list(map(int, input().split()))` in this code.

Comment: @vnk No. I want to ask why the first function `find_max_score` works with a map but the second function `find_runner_up_score` does not work.

Comment: This is because, in the first case you are creating a map object which is a stateful iterator. This means that it can only be looped over once. This is what happens when you call `find_max_score` first. Once that's done, the whole object is looped over and there's nothing left to iterate by the time  `find_runner_up_score` is called.

Comment: @vnk Please add this to your answer. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @SiddharthManthan  I've already added. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code treats `arr` as a **list** but the input is in the **map object** format. Just replace `arr = map(int, input().split())` with:

```
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
```